# Calling the shell commands from os.system not working

Tags: python, shell

I'm very new to python and I have code like this:

```
os.system(''' PROMPT_COMMAND="printf '%*s\n' "${COLUMNS:-$(tput cols)}" '' | tr ' ' -" ''')
```

the part:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="printf '%*s\n' "${COLUMNS:-$(tput cols)}" '' | tr ' ' -"
```

does print `-` to fill up the shell width. The above command is working as expected in the command prompt. But when I did in python. I'm getting no output at all.

Comment: `os.system` is deprecated. It's replaced by the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module. `subprocess.Popen` is what you could use here.

Answer (score 2):

There is no point of issuing this command at all.

As I understand it, you are just setting the environment variable `PROMPT_COMMAND` in order to make the shell execute it on every prompt.

But setting an environment variable has only an impact of a called shell, but not to the caller. You cannot change the environment of your parent process.

Answer (score -1):

This will do. As I see the problem is with the quotes:

```
import os

PROMPT_COMMAND = 'printf "%*s\n" "${COLUMNS:-$(tput cols)}" "" | tr " " -'
os.system(PROMPT_COMMAND)
```